# jquery submit is not stopping the form from being submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html form

```
<form action="/newPost" id="submit_new" method="get"><div class="iwill">
    <div class="iwill-holder">
        <div class="txt"></div><div class="f"><input class="text" id="quickpost" name="quickpost" type="text" value=""></div>
        <div class="img regularProgress" alt="Processing..."><input alt="Continue" class="iwill-btn movable" id="continue_submit" src="<?=$config['http']?>images/btn-2-continue-gray.png" type="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the jquery function :

```
$('#submit_new').submit(function() {

var error = 0;

    var quickpost = $("#quickpost").val();
    if( quickpost == '' ) {
    $("#quickpost").effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);
    $('#quickpost').css("color","red");
    $('#quickpost').css("border","red 1px solid");
    error = 1;

    }else{
      $('#quickpost').css("border","gray 1px solid");
      $('#quickpost').css("color","black");
      error = 0;
    }


    if(errorCounter > 0){
      return false;
    }else{

        $.ajax({
                  url: 'sendPost.php?quickpost='+quickpost,
                  success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').prepend(data).slideDown('slow', function() {});

                  }
                });
    }
    return false;
});
```

technically I am trying to post the form values using ajax, but whatever I do the form still gets submitted to action page. I have tried to even make all paths lead to `false` but its not working

Comment: Are you wrapping this in a $(document).ready( ?

Comment: James is probably right. Also can you check in FireFox error console, whether any javascript error is terminating the flow of function (so false does not get return to Jquery invoker function) and form is getting submitted.

Comment: No I am adding the javascript code after the form... so I guess there is no need for that right?

Comment: @jatanp I checked in chrome error console and no errors are shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try preventing the default behavior

```
$('#submit_new').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
...
```

You also have a typo

```
if(errorCounter > 0){
    return false;
}else{
```

should be:

```
if(error > 0){
    return false;
}else{
```

Comment: I am not submitting the form by clicking on the submit button I am just pressing enter, I know this sounds like a noob question but wouldnt that mean that the above function wont be called?

Comment: The event is triggered by pressing enter or clicking the submit button. Your code failed because errorCounter was undefiend because you used the variable error and not errorCounter

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#submit_new').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //other stuff
});
```

You need a preventDefault() in the submit function.

Answer (score 1):

I got a version still use `return false` to prevent form submit
http://jsfiddle.net/pKR6G/2/

NB: I've commented out the line of shake effect so I don't need to include jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

The event listener method does not care what you return from a listener function. You need to use the jquery preventdefault method on the passed in event object.

Comment: Thats not true: `return false;` is similar to (`event = arguments[0]`) `event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();`